# How to escape curly brackets in xslt definition

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Error"
      internalLogFile="internal-nlog.txt">
  <targets async="true">
    <target xsi:type="Null" name="blackhole" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="exceptions"/>
    <logger name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="blackhole" final="true"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

And I want to insert

```
<target xsi:type="Bugsnag" name="bugsnag" apikey="xxx" AppType="${app}" ReleaseStage="Development" />
```

so that it eventually looks like

I tried the xslts like

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:t="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/t:nlog/t:targets">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()" />
            <target xsi:type="Bugsnag" name="bugsnag" apikey="xxx" AppType="$\{app\}" ReleaseStage="Development" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:t="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/t:nlog/t:targets">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()" />
            <target xsi:type="Bugsnag" name="bugsnag" apikey="xxx" AppType="$'{'app'}'" ReleaseStage="Development" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But neither of them are working. The first gives me an error that the input string invalid and the letter inserts `'app'` instead of `${app}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use double braces, or use xsl:attribute elements to add the attributes.

Example (in AppType2 and AppType3 attributes):

```
<target xsi:type="Bugsnag" name="bugsnag" apikey="xxx" AppType="${app}" ReleaseStage="Development" AppType2="${{app}}">
    <xsl:attribute name="AppType3">${app}</xsl:attribute>
</target>
```

generates:

```
<target xmlns="" xsi:type="Bugsnag" name="bugsnag" apikey="xxx" AppType="$" ReleaseStage="Development" AppType2="${app}" AppType3="${app}"/></targets>
```